# Send Birthday Emails to Employees MVC ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a function where I send Email to a user when it their birthday. I have all their personal data in my database, so I just wonder like where do i start? Or what do i do? I'm creating this in an MVC app. This is what I've done so far.

> This is my function in my repository.

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeesBasesOnBirthDate(int customerId, string birthdate)
    {
        return db.Employees.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId && x.BirthDate.Contains(birthdate)).ToList();
    }
```

> And this is what i do in my Controller

```
 public ActionResult BirthdayEmail()
{
    var repository = new SiteRepository();
    var employeebirthday = repository.GetEmployeesBasesOnBirthDate(CommonHelper.CustomerId, DateTime.Now.ToString());

    return View();
}
```

> What do I do now?

Comment: What data type is `Employee.BirthDate`.. It looks like it is a string and not a datetime?

Comment: Employee.BirthDate is a string. But DateTime.Now is taking out all of the employees that have a birthday today.

Comment: The problem is properly that the format of the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is not the same as what you have in your database.

Comment: Okay! But what do i write instead then?

Comment: Since you're new to the site, I thought I would let you know that posting [the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067572/send-birthday-e-mail) is a bit frowned upon over here :)

Comment: @Tempest-MarieNorlin can't tell you without knowing the format of both the `DateTime.Now.ToStrng()` or what you have in your database.. I think it will be best if you change the datatype from `string` to `DateTime` then you can do a simple check if it is the same day

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method which automatically send Emails on their birthdays.

using System.Net.mail; includes a method for mailmessage you can use it to make you mail message body and use your database data to send mail templets to your Employees.

I know it's not the complete solution but if you do little more search on mail templates you will get solution for your code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your method `GetEmployeesBasesOnBirthDate(int customerId, DateTime birthdate)`
And then compare dates, do you need exact time or dates only ?
After that you should loop trough employee list and send email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'll want to send out the emails in an asynchronous fashion rather than from an action method. If that is the case, you will need a background job that:

1. gets fired automatically in the morning
2. retrieves the list of employees that were born on that day
3. actually sends out the emails

For asynchronous jobs you want to look into [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) which, among other things, lets you set up recurring tasks. Moreover, its documentation also includes a [tutorial teaching you how to send mail](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html).

This could be a sound architecture, but if you need more specific answers you'll need to post specific questions.

Note: the fact that dates are stored as strings in the db will cause a lot of grief and ugly parsing all over the place. If at all possible change that to use an actual date type.